# Probability of a random point being in a circle

Tags: probability, geometry

I've got a following math problem. Let point `a` be the origin. We randomly place a circle of radius `r` somewhere on the plane so that the center of the circle is no further then `m` from the origin.
[image]

How do I calculate the probability that the point is inside or on the circle?

Comment: randomly = normal or uniform distribution?

Comment: Do you mean interior point @PanCotzky$?$

Comment: Draw the area where the center can be  at all. (Oh, you already did.) Now draw the area where the center should be so that the circle covers the origin.

Comment: Do you want the probability that a is inside the circle of radius r? If so, can you find the probability that it isn't?

Comment: I think to talk about this probability we have to talk about an "area" of the circumference of the circle?

Comment: If I interpret this correctly, you merely have to consider the radii of the two circles.

Comment: A uniform distribution @V-X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the center of the circle with radius r be $b$.

Valid positions for b is in the region is ${\pi}m^2$

Notice that $a$ will only be in the circle if $b$ lies in the circle ${\pi}r^2$

Hence $P={{\pi}r^2\over {\pi}m^2}={{r^2}\over {m^2}}$